# Newly created xamarin solution getting errors on xamarin.forms and application inherited type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Every time I create a new solution in vs2017, I get errors on the using Xamarin.Forms directive and also on the app.axml.cs class definition when Application is inherited (which causes errors on the On methods), see image.

Is there a way of modifying the way vs configures solutions upon creation.

![Xamarin Errors](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive/xamarin errors.jpg)

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Also, paste the error message(s) as text so they can be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have access to a site I could store on, so I used google drive, but only I could access it

Answer (score 0):

I did a repair on the IDE, and everything is working now. I wish this version of studio was more stable. All I did was create a new cross platform solution and the errors were present. I could open a solution I had already worked on and it works fine. Go figure!